# no aparece aplicacion multiplataforma xamarin form o nativa en visual studio enterprise 2017

Tags: xamarin

estoy iniciando en el mundo de las app con xamarin y estoy revisando donde abren un nuevo proyecto en aplicacion multiplataforma xamarin form o nativa, pero en el xamarin que yo tengo instalado no tiene esta opción.

se tiene que habilitar? o instalar alguna herramienta extra para esto?

Comment: Te dejo este enlace a ver si te puede ayudar. https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/xamarin/cross-platform/get-started/installation/windows

Comment: no, no tienes que instalar nada extra si al instalar visual studio seleccionaste la opción de "Desarrollo para dispositivos moviles con .NET" si no es el caso, ve al link que te puso mourazo para hacer la instalación adecuada.